# UK Visa Expires in Aug

Tags: visas, uk

I plan to travel to London in June and my Visa expires in August. Is it ok to travel? Or do I need to have atleast 6 months' validity before the Visa expires?

Comment: You seem to have several rules cross-wired with each other. Probably something that was vectored on the net. What you wrote appears to be a very normal case and should not (in itself) raise any flags.